# qt creator version 5.3: quitting whole application if one mainwindow is closed

Tags: qt, definition, quit, close-application

I am trying to use the `QCloseEvent` to close all my dialogs and quit the application when the main window closes. I have read the documentation and looked at many examples and this is what I've come up with so far:

In my .h file:

```
protected:

void mainwindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent * );
```

In my mainwindow.cpp file:

```
class QCloseEvent;
void mainwindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    event->accept();

    if (event->isAccepted())
    {
        QApplication::quit();
    }

}
```

when I run this code I get the following errors:
`mainwindow::closeEvent'` : local function definitions are illegal
mainwindow.cpp(13): this line contains a '{' which has not yet been matched

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with function declaration in your .h file :

```
void mainwindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent * );
```

It should be :

```
void closeEvent(QCloseEvent * );
```

Also include `QCloseEvent` instead of `class QCloseEvent;`.

Comment: I changed the header file as suggested and i still get the following error mainwindow.cpp:22: error: C2601: 'mainwindow::closeEvent' : local function definitions are illegal
simmotioncontrol.cpp(13): this line contains a '{' which has not yet been matched... the errors are showing up in my .cpp file, not the .h file if that helps

Comment: Remove the forward declaration from the cpp, which is `class QCloseEvent;` and include `QCloseEvent` header into either your cpp or h file.

Comment: I did that as well and now I get the same error as before (local function definitions are illegal) thank you for your help


    void simMotionControl::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
        {
            event->accept();

            if (event->isAccepted())
            {
                QApplication::quit();
            }
            return;
        }

Comment: I found the problem. I was putting the code just after (inside the brakets) `ui->setupUi(this);` i just had to take the code outside those brakets